# Exception Value: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'backend'

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, backend

Also I got this error `'tuple' object has no attribute` 'backend' when I do `@login_required(login_url = "/oauth2/login")`

But when I just go to `/oauth2/login` all works fine.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gluko/discord/GhostSide/GhostSideenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/gluko/discord/GhostSide/GhostSideenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/gluko/discord/GhostSide/apps/oauth2/views.py", line 55, in discord_login_redirect
    discord_user = authenticate(request, user = user)
  File "/home/gluko/discord/GhostSide/GhostSideenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 42, in sensitive_variables_wrapper
    return func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/home/gluko/discord/GhostSide/GhostSideenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 85, in authenticate
    user.backend = backend_path

Exception Type: AttributeError at /oauth2/login/redirect
Exception Value: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'backend'
```

Comment: not enough information. error says, you has a wrong settings for authorization backend. problem is not in decorator.

Comment: I add Traceback

Comment: traceback says, that you here give not user, you give a tuple. discord_user = authenticate(request, user = user). can you give a code of discord_login_redirect ?